# downloaded image unable to view in gallery

Tags: android, url, download, gallery, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download image and save it to app folder as shown below and everything works fine.

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            storagepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/DownloadedImages");

            if (!storagepath.exists()) {
                storagepath.mkdirs();
            }
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(storagepath + "/" + filewithoutextension + ".bmp");
            Intent intent =
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(storagepath));
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            Savetogallery(storagepath);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

    }
```

Now my problem is the downloaded image which is in particular folder not showing up in gallery when I use intent to open as shown below:

```
btnOpenpath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 10);
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                }

            }
 });
```

If I use the download manager as shown below then its showing with the folder name.

```
    public void downloadFile(String uRl) {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/SampleFolder");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
            .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/SampleFolder", "fileName.jpg");

    mgr.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: @downvoter-Care to comment please? Did you understand what I have asked or something you havent understood please let me know will update my question

Comment: hi. your bug is gallery screen not show downloaded image which you stored in folder ?

Comment: @GiapLee- Yes..so how can I see the downloaded image using the gallery screen

Comment: yes i see so i have voted up for you. wait me for support.

Answer (score 2):

Read and try example code bellow:

note: i use Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE to notify to OS scan and update newest file

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{
        Intent imageScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File newestFile = new File("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)); //you can replace with particular folder here
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(newestFile );
        imageScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        mycontext.sendBroadcast(imageScanIntent);
}
else
{
        mycontext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); //you can replace or add/concat particular folder which you download image into
}
```

you can ref more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html)

Comment: @GiapLee- what is mediaScanIntent here ?

Comment: instead of folder, if you pass the downloaded File dierectly, it scans faster and shows in Gallery.